# iPhone OpenGL-ES Video Texture

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, avassetreader

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple here...

I have an AR application that displays a 3D object upon marker detection. The object is simply a flat 3d rectangle - which I am able to bind image textures to without issue. However, I need to bind a video file (.m4v) as the objects texture. I am successfully reading the file with a **AVAssetReader**, however when binding the texture like so, the object just appears white.

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [mOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 320, 240, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer));
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );    
CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
```

I'd appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default texture parameters](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture) require a complete set of mipmaps.

Try using `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`.

You may also need power-of-two texture dimensions.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have made that correction now. New problem is that its projecting the texture as a camera stream - so it appears my AVAssetReader isn't working correctly. Strange because I am able to pull the frames out and save them as individually as images, only when its projected it appears as a camera feed.